# why package.json need main and start java script

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

in package.json, if main is defined and pointing to a java script file, what is the purpose of start within scripts attribute. Can I remove either java script ?

```
"main": "xyz.js",
"scripts": {
"star":"node your-script.js"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `start` script is used to run your project for example using `npm start`.

But the `main` field is an indicator of the entry point for your project that is used to load you module when you're building a module/library to be used in other projects.

Here's a link to the documentation:
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main

Comment: Thanks, that does mean if I am not building a library, main field can be removed